# Using @OneToOne with Cascade.DELETE in embedded type

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, cascade, one-to-one

In an application I use EclipseLink 2.4.1 with Java Persistence 2.0.4.

I have a OneToOne mapping in an embedded class. Everything works fine, except deleting. When I try to delete the object containing the embedded class, the following exception occurs. I checked and **I am not calling remove on the embedded object by myself** somewhere in the code. Does anybody knows how to avoid this error or how to get around it?

```
Exception [EclipseLink-6002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: Aggregated objects cannot be written/deleted/queried independently from their owners. 
Descriptor: [RelationalDescriptor(org.openlca.web.model.ProcessModelInfo --> [])]
Query: DeleteObjectQuery(org.openlca.web.model.ProcessModelInfo@77cc2975)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException.aggregateObjectCannotBeDeletedOrWritten(QueryException.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.prepare(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DeleteObjectQuery.prepare(DeleteObjectQuery.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.checkPrepare(DatabaseQuery.java:614)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.checkPrepare(DatabaseQuery.java:575)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:820)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:751)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWorkObjectLevelModifyQuery(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DeleteObjectQuery.executeInUnitOfWorkObjectLevelModifyQuery(DeleteObjectQuery.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2875)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1602)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1584)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1535)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DeleteObjectQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(DeleteObjectQuery.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:852)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:751)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWorkObjectLevelModifyQuery(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DeleteObjectQuery.executeInUnitOfWorkObjectLevelModifyQuery(DeleteObjectQuery.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2875)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1602)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1584)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1535)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.deleteAllObjects(CommitManager.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.deleteAllObjects(CommitManager.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabase(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1422)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.commitToDatabase(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:634)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1509)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.commitRootUnitOfWork(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:266)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitAndResume(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1147)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commitInternal(EntityTransactionImpl.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:63)
    at org.project.ProcessDao.delete(ProcessDao.java:41)
```

The relevant class snippets look like this (Process and LongText are added in the persistence.xml) - The error occurs when trying to delete a process:

Entity Class Process

```
@Entity
public class Process {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "process_seq")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    ....

    @Embedded
    private ProcessModelInfo modelInfo = new ProcessModelInfo();

    ....

}
```

Embedded Class ProcessModelInfo

```
@Embeddable
public class ProcessModelInfo {

    ...

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name= "f_modelling_constants")
    private LongText modellingConstants = new LongText();

    ...

}
```

Entity Class LongText

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_long_texts")
public class LongText {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "long_text_seq")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "text")
    private String text;

    ....

}
```

The ProcessDao.delete method looks like this:

```
@Override
public void delete(Process entity) throws Exception {
    if (entity == null)
        return;
    EntityManager em = createManager();
    try {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.remove(em.merge(entity));
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
```

}

Comment: I was able to reproduce the same problem with a different example. The problem only occurs if the @OneToOne relationship is inside an embedded object; if I move the same aggregation without the embedded object, it works fine. Is this an Eclipselink bug?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see how this would occur, but if you can create a reproducible test case, please log a bug.

Check that you don't have any events that may be call remove on the embeddable.
Try debugging or set logging level to finest.

You may want to try the 2.5 release, as it may have been fixed (although I don't see any changes in the code).