# Eclipselink: Deleting @OneToOne inside embedded with cascading DELETE

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I get an exception ("aggregated objects cannot be written/deleted/queried independently from their owners.") with Eclipelink 2.5.2 when deleting a @OneToOne object via JPA if the @OneToOne relation itself is inside an embedded object. This is similar to:
[Using @OneToOne with Cascade.DELETE in embedded type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17061985/using-onetoone-with-cascade-delete-in-embedded-type)

Complete example:

```
@Entity
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected int id;

    public String title = "foo";

    // @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    // public List<Page> pages = new ArrayList<Page>();  // if pages are directly inside the book (instead of in the embedded BookContext), this example works fine

    @Embedded
    public BookContent bookContent;

    public Book() {
        bookContent = new BookContent();
        // pages.add(new Page()); // if this is used instead of bookContent, then it works
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Book");
            EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
            Book book = new Book();

            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.persist(book);
            em.getTransaction().commit(); 

            em.getTransaction().begin();
            Query query = em.createQuery("Select g from Book g"); // of course in this example the query would not be necessary
            List<Book> results = query.getResultList();
            for (Book bookToRemove : results){
                em.remove(bookToRemove);
            }
            em.getTransaction().commit();
            em.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}

@Embeddable
public class BookContent {
    @OneToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    public Page page;

    public String bookdContentID = "1";

    public BookContent() {
        page = new Page();
    }
}

@Entity
public class Page {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected int id;

    public String text = "test";
}
```

When I run this, I get the following error ("Aggregated objects cannot be written/deleted/queried independently from their owners.")

```
[EL Fine]: sql: 2014-07-31 14:51:41.157--ClientSession(907509627)--Connection(2114173229)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--DELETE FROM BOOK_PAGE WHERE (Book_ID = ?)
    bind => [1]
[EL Finest]: query: 2014-07-31 14:51:41.159--UnitOfWork(811619113)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Execute query DeleteObjectQuery(Page@577a863d)
[EL Finest]: query: 2014-07-31 14:51:41.159--UnitOfWork(811619113)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Execute query DeleteObjectQuery(BookContent@4b9f8b6c)
[EL Warning]: 2014-07-31 14:51:41.164--UnitOfWork(811619113)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-6002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: Aggregated objects cannot be written/deleted/queried independently from their owners. 
Descriptor: [RelationalDescriptor(BookContent --> [])]
Query: DeleteObjectQuery(BookContent@4b9f8b6c)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException.aggregateObjectCannotBeDeletedOrWritten(QueryException.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.prepare(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DeleteObjectQuery.prepare(DeleteObjectQuery.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.checkPrepare(DatabaseQuery.java:661)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.checkPrepare(DatabaseQuery.java:613)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:867)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:798)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWorkObjectLevelModifyQuery(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DeleteObjectQuery.executeInUnitOfWorkObjectLevelModifyQuery(DeleteObjectQuery.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2896)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1804)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1786)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1737)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DeleteObjectQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(DeleteObjectQuery.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:899)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:798)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWorkObjectLevelModifyQuery(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DeleteObjectQuery.executeInUnitOfWorkObjectLevelModifyQuery(DeleteObjectQuery.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2896)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1804)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1786)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1737)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.deleteAllObjects(CommitManager.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.deleteAllObjects(CommitManager.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabase(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1444)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1531)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.commitRootUnitOfWork(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitAndResume(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1169)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:132)
    at Book.main(Book.java:53)

[EL Finer]: transaction: 2014-07-31 14:51:41.165--ClientSession(907509627)--Connection(2114173229)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--rollback transaction
[EL Finest]: connection: 2014-07-31 14:51:41.166--ServerSession(228859333)--Connection(2114173229)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Connection released to connection pool [default].
[EL Finer]: transaction: 2014-07-31 14:51:41.166--UnitOfWork(811619113)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--release unit of work
[EL Finer]: connection: 2014-07-31 14:51:41.166--ClientSession(907509627)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--client released
javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-6002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: Aggregated objects cannot be written/deleted/queried independently from their owners. 
Descriptor: [RelationalDescriptor(BookContent --> [])]
Query: DeleteObjectQuery(BookContent@4b9f8b6c)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:157)
    at Book.main(Book.java:53)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-6002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: Aggregated objects cannot be written/deleted/queried independently from their owners. 
Descriptor: [RelationalDescriptor(BookContent --> [])]
Query: DeleteObjectQuery(BookContent@4b9f8b6c)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException.aggregateObjectCannotBeDeletedOrWritten(QueryException.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.prepare(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DeleteObjectQuery.prepare(DeleteObjectQuery.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.checkPrepare(DatabaseQuery.java:661)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.checkPrepare(DatabaseQuery.java:613)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:867)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:798)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWorkObjectLevelModifyQuery(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DeleteObjectQuery.executeInUnitOfWorkObjectLevelModifyQuery(DeleteObjectQuery.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2896)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1804)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1786)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1737)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DeleteObjectQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(DeleteObjectQuery.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:899)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:798)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWorkObjectLevelModifyQuery(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DeleteObjectQuery.executeInUnitOfWorkObjectLevelModifyQuery(DeleteObjectQuery.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2896)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1804)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1786)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1737)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.deleteAllObjects(CommitManager.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.deleteAllObjects(CommitManager.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabase(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1444)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1531)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.commitRootUnitOfWork(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitAndResume(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1169)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:132)
    ... 1 more
```

If I instead remove the "Bookcontent", and include the "Page" object directly in the Book object, then all works fine:

```
[EL Fine]: sql: 2014-07-31 15:10:45.241--ClientSession(1901887672)--Connection(2055970986)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--DELETE FROM BOOK_PAGE WHERE (Book_ID = ?)
    bind => [1]
[EL Finest]: query: 2014-07-31 15:10:45.242--UnitOfWork(404057375)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Execute query DeleteObjectQuery(Page@7a9a042)
[EL Fine]: sql: 2014-07-31 15:10:45.243--ClientSession(1901887672)--Connection(2055970986)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--DELETE FROM PAGE WHERE (ID = ?)
    bind => [1]
[EL Finest]: query: 2014-07-31 15:10:45.245--UnitOfWork(404057375)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Execute query DeleteObjectQuery(Book@26af1a93)
[EL Fine]: sql: 2014-07-31 15:10:45.246--ClientSession(1901887672)--Connection(2055970986)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--DELETE FROM BOOK WHERE (ID = ?)
    bind => [1]
[EL Finer]: transaction: 2014-07-31 15:10:45.247--ClientSession(1901887672)--Connection(2055970986)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--commit transaction
[EL Finest]: connection: 2014-07-31 15:10:45.248--ServerSession(686104144)--Connection(2055970986)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Connection released to connection pool [default].
[EL Finer]: transaction: 2014-07-31 15:10:45.248--UnitOfWork(404057375)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--end unit of work commit
[EL Finer]: transaction: 2014-07-31 15:10:45.248--UnitOfWork(404057375)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--resume unit of work
[EL Finer]: transaction: 2014-07-31 15:10:45.249--UnitOfWork(404057375)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--release unit of work
[EL Finer]: connection: 2014-07-31 15:10:45.249--ClientSession(1901887672)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--client released
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually it is working but the Embeddable cannot be on the owning side of the relationship. I created an example with switched ownership and it worked perfectly. I assume following words from the section 2.5 of the spec apply:

> Since instances of
>   embeddable classes themselves have no persistent identity, the relationship *from* the referenced entity is
>   to the *entity* that contains the embeddable instance(s) and not to the embeddable itself. [An entity cannot have a unidirectional relationship to the embeddable class of another entity (or itself).]

The stripped down example that is working:

```
@Embeddable
public class BookContent {
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="book",cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    Page page;
}

@Entity
public class Book {
    @Id @GeneratedValue int id;

    @Embedded
    public BookContent bookContent;
}

@Entity
public class Page {
    @Id @GeneratedValue int id;

    @OneToOne
    Book book;
}
```

Note: right now the `Page` is the owner of the relationship.

I assume that having Book with one Page is not what we usually see, so I also checked `@OneToMany` to be working fine.

```
// BookContent
@OneToMany(mappedBy="book",cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
List<Page> page;

// Page
@ManyToOne
Book book;
```

**UPDATE**
The ownership of the relation in embeddable is actually valid according to API Javadoc:

> If the relationship is bidirectional and the entity containing the embeddable class is on the owning side of the relationship, the non-owning side must use the mappedBy element of the OneToOne annotation to specify the relationship field or property of the embeddable class. The dot (".") notation syntax must be used in the mappedBy element to indicate the relationship attribute within the embedded attribute.

But even if properly mapped the Eclipselink don't allow removing.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know the reason for this restriction? So far I was using Hibernate with the same code and it worked fine.
I am not sure that the solution would work for me (it would likely work for this simple example, but not for my real code). First, I use JAXB to generate XML from the objects, and the XML schema is fixed, so I cannot change the structure (although there may be some workaround). More importantly, I have other objects that have a OneToOne mapping to "Page" (in my real code, it's not a "page", but some other object, which is why I used OneToOne and not OneToMany here).